# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-core, null

Почему объект в этом случае audience == null, если в базе есть объекты?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Администратор")]
public class AudienceController : Controller {
    private readonly ApplicationContext db;

    public AudienceController(ApplicationContext context) {
        db = context;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Occupy(MyViewModelSearch model) {

        if (model.SearchAuditMod != null) {

            MyViewModelSearch modelforsearch = new MyViewModelSearch {
                AudiencesMod = await db.Audiences.ToListAsync(),
            };

            foreach (Audience audience in modelforsearch.AudiencesMod) {
                if (audience.Building == model.SearchAuditMod.Building) {

                    model.AudiencesMod.Append(audience);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModelSearch {
    public IEnumerable<Audience> AudiencesMod { get; set; }
    public SearchAuditViewModel SearchAuditMod { get; set; }
}
```

Audience:

```
public class Audience {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Корпус")]
    public string Building { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Номер аудитории")]
    public int Number { get; set; } 

    public bool Projector { get; set; } 
    public bool Computer { get; set; } 
}
```

SearchAuditViewModel :

```
public class SearchAuditViewModel {
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
    public int max { get; set; }
    public bool Projector { get; set; }
    public bool Computer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyViewModelSearch {
  public IEnumerable<Audience> AudiencesMod { get; set; }
  public SearchAuditViewModel SearchAuditMod { get; set; }
  public MyViewModelSearch()
  {
    AudiencesMod = new List<Audience>();
    SearchAuditMod = new SearchAuditViewModel();
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка пропала. Но теперь почему-то не выводятся в представлении те объекты, что были добавлены в модель.
@{ if (Model.AudiencesMod != null) {
                            @foreach (var item in Model.AudiencesMod) {
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="p-2 pt-3">@item.Building-@item.Number</td>
....

Comment: @Panthevm Вы уверены, что туда было что-то добавлено?

Comment: @Panthevm Попробуйте убрать условие `audience.Building == ...`

Comment: При помощи Append объект не добавляется в список?

Comment: Все равно не выводится

Comment: Разобрался. Как говорят IEnumerable не предназначена для того чтобы добавлять в нее значения. С List<> и методом Add все работает как надо.
Еще раз благодарю за помощь!